# Proper way to load in html file from resources into UIWebView?

Tags: ios, resources, uiwebview, local, nsurl

I thought it would be easy to load in a html file from my resources into a UIWebView, but it looks like it requires something extra that I'm not doing. So far I have in my viewDidLoad in my controller:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"radialGradient.html"];
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:req];

webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024);
```

I've tried regular web addresses (google.com) and it works fine. But with the file in my sources it just renders a white blank screen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two things:

1)

What you have now is not a URL.  It's just a filename.  You need to be prepending a "file:///" in front of that radialGradient.html.

2)

And, you'll likely also need to put in a resolvable path to radialGradient.html  Right now your app doesn't know where to look for it.

Something like:

```
NSURL * resourcePathURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL];
if(resourcePathURL)
{
    NSURL * urlToLoad = [resourcePathURL URLByAppendingPathComponent: @"radialGradient.html"];
    if(urlToLoad)
    {
        NSURLRequest * req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: urlToLoad];
        [webView loadRequest: req];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I tried adding "file:///" or "file://" and "file://Resources" with no luck. (whole path is @"file://Resources/radialGradient.html")

Comment: I was trying to nudge you along the path to a solution instead of just handing it all over :-)  I have changed my answer to include source code you can use.

Comment: Okay thanks! I'll read this through and see why it is needed. Thanks again